# trying to solve workbooks.open in filedirectory error

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I feel very silly and I'm stuck.

I would like to open a file on the following location:
F:\users\DC Holwerda, Almere\Logistieke accounts\AA. Logistiek Thom\Data analyse 2022\Keukens Analyse\Query Talis

I can't get workbooks.open to work. Has something changed?

see the code below:

```
Sub openfile()

Workbooks.Open "F:\users\DC Holwerda, Almere\Logistieke accounts\AA. Logistiek Thom\Data analyse 2022\Keukens Analyse\Query Talis\Forecast.xlsx"

End Sub
```

when I run the code the following error pop's up:

[image: error uppon executing VBA]

translated to English: a function or variable is expected

Comment: That's your exact code?  Looks OK to me...

Comment: yess, copied it from VBA

Comment: That's a compile-time error?  If you run *Debug >> Compile VBAProject* in the VBE do you see that?

Comment: yes, it says the same as the image I sent: a function or variable is expected

Comment: Is there something else in your workbook named "Workbooks" ?  Another Sub maybe?  I see that error if I create a Sub called `Workbooks`.

Comment: your rigth, if I make a new workbook and put the same vba in a module it works. I've put an ' before every workbooks but get the same error. Do I have to delete them?

Comment: Do you have a `Sub Workbooks()` in the workbook where you have a problem?  That's the only thing you need to fix - just rename it to something else.

Comment: Right-click on the `Workbooks`-part of the `Open`-statement. If the Editor jumps to a piece of your code, you found your mistake: You have a routine names `Workbooks` and this hides the the global `Workbooks`-object. With other words: the VBA compiler has to decide which `Workbooks` is meant and as it cannot guess, it assumes that your Sub has to be called, and this results in an syntax error. As Tim Williams said, just rename your routine.